# Collect user custom field in product page woocommerce

Tags: custom-field, plugins

I have a custom user field named "weight" and I need to collect this information in woo product page.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/get-user-custom-field-values/other_notes/   you can use  thos plugin to solve you problums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields  you can also  get all the detail manually from here